# How to display seconds of the timer in the output screen?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Java {
  Toolkit toolkit;
  Timer timer;
int t=10000,total;
  public Java(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    total =seconds * t;
    System.out.println(total);
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), total); 
  }

  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {        
      System.out.println("Time's up!");
      toolkit.beep();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Java(5);
    System.out.println("Timer started");
  }
}
```

How can I display the seconds similar to countdown timer in output screen, I want to use it in a quiz program

0:53  =>  0:52  *like this* ...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is schedule a task at a fixed rate (`Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`) using a period of `1 second`. As far as possible, we should refrain from calling the `System.exit(0)` and wait for the threads to complete their tasks. We can make the main thread (the thread that started the timer) sleep for the duration of the timer tasks and then when it finally wakes up, it cancels the timer:

```
private final Timer timer;
public CountDownTimer(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(seconds), 0, 1000);
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    private volatile int remainingTimeInSeconds;
    public RemindTask(int remainingTimeInSeconds) {
        this.remainingTimeInSeconds = remainingTimeInSeconds;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (remainingTimeInSeconds != 0) {
            System.out.println(remainingTimeInSeconds + " ...");
            remainingTimeInSeconds -= 1;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer(5);
    System.out.println("Timer started");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    t.end();
}

private void end() {
    this.timer.cancel();
}
```